# How do I pass a variable from my local Python code to a remote PHP script that writes to a MySQL database?

Tags: python, php, mysql

On my local PC I want to use Python to both send and receive data on a remote MySQL database, via a PHP file that is located on the same webserver as the MySQL database.

I can already UPDATE the MySQL database when I run the following PHP script on the webserver:

```
<?php
$host_name = 'host';
$database = 'db';
$user_name = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

$conn = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
  
$sql = "UPDATE test
SET test = 1
WHERE test = 0";
  
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
  
$conn->close();
?>
```

I have searched for hours but so far cannot make any decent attempt at Python code that will send a variable to the PHP code that will in turn update the MySQL database.

The PHP file seems to be publicly accessible so I don't imagine webserver credentials are required in my Python?

Thank you in advance SO!

Comment: What have you tried to do in Python? The `requests` library is popular for making HTTP requests from Python, and should be straight forward to call with the URL to your PHP script (`import requests, requests.get('https://example.com/foo.php')`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.

Does that Python you've posted have to target a PHP file that runs a GET?  Currently all that's returned by `requests.get('https://example.com/foo.php')` is a 200

Comment: @INoble yes it would. But python is perfectly capable of sending POSTs too. A bit of simple research will get you there... (as well as the answer below)

Answer (score 2):

With a local PHP server running using `php -S localhost:8881 receive.php`

send.py

```
import requests

url = 'http://localhost:8881'

myobj = {'key1': 'value1'}

x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)

print (x.text)
```

receive.php

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);
```

Output of running send.py will be:

```
array(1) {
    ["key1"]=>
    string(6) "value1"
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly for a GET

Can you help me out with a POST also?  The main thing I'm looking to do is make changes, via Python -> PHP -> MySQL

Answer (score 0):

For future potential visitors, below is the combination of Python and PHP that finally wrote a value from my local Python file -> to the remote PHP file -> which wrote successfully to a MySQL database.

I write the integer 6 where the value 2 exists in the database table.

Python:

```
import requests

url = 'https://url/file_name.php'

myobj = {'key1': 6}

x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)

print (x.text)
```

PHP on server (file_name.php):

```
<?php
$host_name = 'hostname';
$database = 'db_name';
$user_name = 'user_name';
$password = 'password';

$conn = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Set variable post_data to equal the value of 'key1', which also had to be converted into an integer
$post_data = intval($_POST['key1']);
  
// SQL Query
$sql = "UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = $post_data
WHERE value = 2";
  
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
  
$conn->close();
?>
```

I get the feeling there's probably a lot of useless information in the PHP file, but I'm a PHP newbie and just glad it's working now :)